# How can i get the colors by product with linq?

Tags: c#, linq

My colors class is

```
public partial class Colors
    {
        public Colors()
        {
            this.Products = new HashSet<Products>();
        }

        public int ColorID { get; set; }
        public string Hex { get; set; }
        public string ColorName { get; set; }
        public int ProductCount { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Products> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

my product class is

```
public partial class Products
{
    public Products()
    {
        this.Colors = new HashSet<Colors>();
    }

    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Colors> Colors { get; set; }
}
```

How can i get the colors by product with linq and set it at the `ProductCount` property?

Comment: What is wrong with `this.Products.Count()` in `ProductCount ` setter?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev The classes are generated by visual studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have noted that this class is auto-generated. And possibly, you don't want to change it's implementation, then you can add extension method for `Colors` class intances and remove the `ProductCount` property:

```
public partial class Colors
    {
        public Colors()
        {
            this.Products = new HashSet<Products>();
        }

        public int ColorID { get; set; }
        public string Hex { get; set; }
        public string ColorName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Products> Products { get; set; }
    }

public static class EntityExtensions
{
    public static int GetProductCount(this Colors colors)
    {
        return colors.Products.Count();
    }
}
```

And then use this as:

```
var productCOunt = colors.GetProductCount();
```

***P.S:*** I suggest to change `Colors` entity name to `Color`. You can choose this option in VS while creating entities.

Answer (score 2):

You should make `Products` non-virtual, make `ProductCount` calculated, or drop `ProductCount` altogether. In other words, `ProductCount` should not remain a manually settable property while `Products` is virtual.

I would opt for dropping `ProductCount`, because users of your library can always do

```
myColor.Products.Count
```

instead of

```
myColor.ProductCount
```

If this is not desirable, make a calculated property without a setter:

```
public int ProductCount => Products.Count; // C# 6
```

or if you are using the old syntax

```
public int ProductCount { get { return Products.Count; } }
```

**Note:** It is very strange for a `Color` to reference all products that have that color, because the relationship that you are modeling goes the opposite way (i.e. "a product has a color", not the other way around).

Comment: I must admit i learned a lot fo things from your answer but i am not so sure i should drop the product count property since i need to return the Colors as an IEnumerable<Colors> for later displaying within a grid